# How to apply liquibase changelog in jhipster spring project

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, liquibase

I have an jhipster spring boot application, where I have 2 Entities, while generating the entities the db was not generated to my liking. For example my entities had a relationship connected through the id but I wanted to connect them through a different field.

For this the first thing I did was comment out all changelogs in my master.xml and I wanted to change my database step by step. I started with my first changelog, I generated another changelog and copied the data from the original just changing the changesetId and the desired values. But when I try to run mvn liquibase:update or run the application I get this error:

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20210126_removed_id_from_price.xml::20210126-1::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table "MATERIAL_PRICE" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.material_price (amount DECIMAL(21, 2) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_MATERIAL_PRICE PRIMARY KEY (amount)) [42101-200] [Failed SQL: (42101) CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.material_price (amount DECIMAL(21, 2) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_MATERIAL_PRICE PRIMARY KEY (amount))]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:646)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:83)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:366)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(DataSourceClosingSpringLiquibase.java:46)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:118)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:93)
    at io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table "MATERIAL_PRICE" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.material_price (amount DECIMAL(21, 2) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_MATERIAL_PRICE PRIMARY KEY (amount)) [42101-200] [Failed SQL: (42101) CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.material_price (amount DECIMAL(21, 2) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_MATERIAL_PRICE PRIMARY KEY (amount))]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:402)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:59)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:131)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1276)
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1258)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:609)
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "MATERIAL_PRICE" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.material_price (amount DECIMAL(21, 2) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_MATERIAL_PRICE PRIMARY KEY (amount)) [42101-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.CreateTable.update(CreateTable.java:89)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:228)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:398)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

So how can I generate a changelog where the changes are taken from it? I am kinda new to liquibase.

HEre are my changelogs:

original:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.9.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">


    <!--
        Added the entity MaterialPrice.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20210124151850-1" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="material_price">
            <column name="id" type="bigint">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="amount" type="decimal(21,2)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here -->
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="20210124151850-1-relations" author="jhipster">

    </changeSet>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changeset - JHipster will add changesets here -->

    <!--
        Load sample data generated with Faker.js
        - This data can be easily edited using a CSV editor (or even MS Excel) and
          is located in the 'src/main/resources/config/liquibase/fake-data' directory
        - By default this data is applied when running with the JHipster 'dev' profile.
          This can be customized by adding or removing 'faker' in the 'spring.liquibase.contexts'
          Spring Boot configuration key.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20210124151850-1-data" author="jhipster" context="faker">
        <loadData
                  file="config/liquibase/fake-data/material_price.csv"
                  separator=";"
                  tableName="material_price">
            <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
            <column name="amount" type="numeric"/>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-loadcolumn - JHipster (and/or extensions) can add load columns here -->
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

My own generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.9.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">


    <!--
        Added the entity MaterialPrice.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20210126-1" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="material_price">
            <column name="amount" type="decimal(21,2)">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here -->
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet id="20210124151850-1-relations" author="jhipster">

    </changeSet>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changeset - JHipster will add changesets here -->

    <!--
        Load sample data generated with Faker.js
        - This data can be easily edited using a CSV editor (or even MS Excel) and
          is located in the 'src/main/resources/config/liquibase/fake-data' directory
        - By default this data is applied when running with the JHipster 'dev' profile.
          This can be customized by adding or removing 'faker' in the 'spring.liquibase.contexts'
          Spring Boot configuration key.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20210124151850-1-data" author="jhipster" context="faker">
        <loadData
            file="config/liquibase/fake-data/material_price.csv"
            separator=";"
            tableName="material_price">
            <column name="id" type="numeric"/>
            <column name="amount" type="numeric"/>
            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-loadcolumn - JHipster (and/or extensions) can add load columns here -->
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

Comment: Seems like the error is saying the object already exists: Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table "MATERIAL_PRICE" already exists; SQL statement:, copying over a changeset and renaming it won't just clean up the db and start over.  Liquibase changelogs are just that, a change...log.  If you want to start over, you have to clear the database, and the databasechangelog.

Comment: how do I do that? with mvn liquibase:update?

Comment: No, you would need to as I said clear your database of all objects that you are trying to create, that you do on your Database, nothing to do with liquibase.  You need to then clear out the rows of your databasechangelog.  The question indicates to me you could benefit from Liquibase's free fundamental course that gets the basics to you hands on in a few hours, try it: https://learn.liquibase.com/ or ask follow up here: https://forum.liquibase.org/